# Termux Bash: ./ Permission Denied

Tags: bash, files, permissions, clang

I have a file `Test.cpp` that I compiled into `test` using `clang++`, but running it, I get the error in the title. I have tried using `chmod u+x test` and `chmod 775 test`, among other commands, but using `ls -l` shows that all files still only have read and write permissions, for example:

`-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a234 media_rw   516 Jan 15 11:58 Sample.cpp`

The `-rw-rw----` is shown on all the files in the directory, even one that I created just now with `nano hello.cpp`, which also couldn't run once compiled

Weirdly though, `Test.py` works when I run it with my installed python program. When I installed python, it looked like it automatically installed clang as well, based on the text it output and the fact that I can compile cpp files

I'm still very new to bash/Linux stuff and I'm guessing that it has something to do with file permissions on Android, but if someone could shed some insight onto this I'd really appreciate it

Edit: removed image, I was lazy and didn't read the rules regarding that, sorry

Comment: What is the filesystem type?

Comment: @NasirRiley how would I go about checking that? I've been searching for about half an hour but the tools that are used in normal Linux either seem to not be available or function differently than expected on my Galaxy Tab S7 FE

Comment: If it's a Galaxy Tab S7 FE, then it's most likely UFS 2.1. Are the files on the local system or are they on removable device like Micro SD card?

Comment: @NasirRiley they're on local storage. I thought filesystem was something like ext2 or ext4, and I thought UFS 2.1 was something more to do with the hardware?

Comment: This question should be on Android Stack Exchange but take note of this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208906/is-it-possible-to-change-file-permissions-on-androids-internal-storage